# Using namespaced functions in jQuery.fn

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-namespaces

This seems like it should be obvious, but I can not figure out how to properly use namespaced (dotted) function names in jQuery.fn.

More precisely, using `this` in a function embedded in an object returns the object.
Not the jQuery object it was attached to via .fn

A simple example that works, not using namespaced functions:
([Working example of the below)](http://www.wquestions.org/stackOverflow/testNamespacedFn.htm)

```
 $.fn.isBigText=function(nBytes) {
    let ttext=this.val();
    if (this.val().length > nBytes ) alert('Too big: '+ttext);
 }
 $.fn.isSmallText=function(nBytes) {
    let ttext=this.val();
    if (ttext.length < nBytes ) alert('Too small: '+ttext);
  }
  function checkSize(evt) {  // alert if too small or big. 
     let jqText=$('#myTextArea') ; // should use evt, but for this example I am being explicit
     jqText.isBigText(20);
     jqText.isSmallText(10);
  }
  ...
  <textarea cols="80" rows="1" id="myTextArea" onChange="checkSize(this)">fill this in </textarea>
```

And a namespaced example that does NOT work.
Not defining a .val() function causes a "TypeError: this.val is not a function" error.
So for illustrative purposes, I define a .val() within myFuncsDef that always returns "This is not the val() I was looking for!"

```
//  this version does not work
 var myFuncsDef={
   val: function() {return 'This is not the val() I was looking for! '},
   bigText:function(nBytes) {
       let ttext=this.val();
        if (this.val().length > nBytes ) alert('Too big: '+ttext);
     } ,
   smallText:function(nBytes) {
      let ttext=this.val();
      if (ttext.length < nBytes ) alert('Too small: '+ttext);
    }
  }
  $.fn.myFuncs=myFuncsDef ;

  function checkSizeNs(evt) {  // alert if too small or big  (namespaced version)
    let jqText=$('#myTextAreaNs') ; // should use evt, but for this example I am being explicit
    jqText.myFuncs.bigText(20);
    jqText.myFuncs.smallText(10);
  }
  ...
  <textarea cols="30" rows="1" id="myTextAreaNs" onChange="checkSizeNs(this)">Fill this </textarea>
```

Perhaps there is a way of saving the proper value of this (the jqText) before calling an internal function (bigText or smallText)?

Of course I could use something like `myFuncs_bigText` instead of `myFuncs.bigText` ...but that seems like a step backward.

Comment: Does `$.fn.isBigText=(nBytes)=>{/*yourcode*/}` solve the problem?

Comment: Note that the `.isBigText` example works fine.  The problem is with the `.myFuncs.bigText` example.  The notion is it would be nice to have a library of such extensions, that can be saved and refered to using a `javacript namespace` syntax. It is not a crucial need, but it would make for a more readable code.

Comment: Which line is the problematic one?

Comment: The problem is that you need your functions to be called with `this` properly bound to the jQuery instance.

Comment: Yes, that is the issue -- how to have `this` properly bound to the jQuery instance. Rather than to the object that contains the function.  And how does one achieve this??

Comment: For Lajos. As noted, the issue is `this` is not pound to the jQuery instance.  This is demonstrated in the `let ttext=this.val();`  line in   `bigText:function(nBytes)` -- the val function called is the one in `myFuncsDef`, not the desired one  -- it is not the function bound to `jqText`. And, as I note before,  removing the `val()` function form `myFuncsDef`  just means you get an undefined error